# Load external JSON into Google Chrome extension script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Google Chrome extension for internal use only (i.e. a developer friend and me would load it using the developer checkbox). Can I load data from a JSON file/ JS file we periodically update into it, without (for convenience sake) repackaging and reloading the extension with that data everytime?

(I've tried things like including a http-localhost url into the manifest json and dynamic js embedding without success.) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are looking into:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html

You need to set permissions on the manifest in order to make cross-origin `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: I wonder if this relates to an old extension version (not 2), as even when setting permissions and web_accessible_resources, then when loading the external URL, Chrome maps it to chrome-extension://something/http ://myurl..."

Comment: More info at http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html . Looking at if there's a way to get it to work with the info there now.

Comment: Sorry, using getUrl when loading the URL was the problem. When setting web_accessible_resources it now works.

Comment: Links don't work anymore. Expiring links is a main reason you don't share links to solutions but you write theme here on SO. This answer as is is now useless.